# LIKE clause on column and group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `postgresql` database and a

table **"phrases"**

with a collection of words/ word groups separated by a "," in each row:

```
id | collection        (text)   | 
---+----------------------------+
 1 | apple tree, large orange   | 
 2 | kiwi, apple tree           | 
 3 | large orange, melon        | 
 4 | large orange, banana beach |
```

and another

table **"pattern"**

with words (some might occur multiple times):

```
id | words   (var char)   | 
---+----------------------+
 1 | apple tree           | 
 2 | large orange         | 
 3 | large orange         |
```

What I want is to have a new table containing the count of occurrences per distinct **words** matching with the **collection** column.

So this:

```
| words        | count |
+--------------+-------+
| apple tree   | 2     |
| large orange | 3     |
```

This is how far I have gotten, but I am stuck:

```
    SELECT phrases.collection
    FROM phrases
    WHERE phrases.collection LIKE any 
                   ( SELECT 
                     ( SELECT ARRAY(
                            SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT('%'::text , pattern.words::text , '%'::text))
                            FROM pattern)
                        )
                    )
```

Even this doesn't seem to do work - and I am completely missing the group by count statement and clueless how to achieve it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unnest(string_to_array(... to expand the phrases into separate rows like so:

```
SELECT words, count(*)
FROM (select distinct words FROM pattern) AS sub1
JOIN (select id, unnest(string_to_array(collection, ', ')) as p  FROM phrases) AS sub2
on words = p
GROUP BY words
;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b02bdb70d4c3f77a6ba9ef8243411ecb)

Comment: `trim(unnest(string_to_array(collection, ',')))` could be more accurate in case if there is no space or there are several spaces after comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT words, COUNT(DISTINCT phrases.id) cnt
FROM phrases
JOIN pattern ON POSITION(words IN collection) > 0
GROUP BY words;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=861a1b0782ac633152386bb5b9f2be30)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
words, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT distinct words FROM pattern) w
LEFT JOIN phrases ON collection LIKE '%' || words || '%'
GROUP BY 1
```

If the type is text, you can concat `'%'` around the pattern to check if exists in the phrase.

The downside is that `%apple tree%` would also match on `pineapple tree`